# Use WHERE clause on a column from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this schema.

```
create table "user" (id serial primary key, name text unique);
create table document (owner integer references "user", ...);
```

I want to select all the documents owned by the user named "vortico". Can I do it in one query? The following doesn't seem to work.

```
select * from document where owner.name = 'vortico';
```

Comment: You need to join tables. That is most basic SQL. Take a SQL tutorial.

Comment: @juergend Thanks. Could you give me a hint on the type of join that could solve this problem?

Comment: The default join: It is `inner join`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM document d INNER JOIN "user" u ON d.owner = u.name 
WHERE u.name = 'vortico'
```

Comment: Perfect! Inner joins have finally clicked for me.

Comment: If u.name = 'vortico' and d.owner = u.name then d.owner = 'vortico'. And then not need for JOIN query.

Comment: Oh yes, the first `u.name` should be `u.id`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use subquery. For your example it can be faster

```
SELECT * FROM document WHERE 
  owner = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = 'vortico');
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to join the tables you need . You can do this with inner join ,left joins depending on what you want to appear. i dont know your schema exactly so here is a link on how inner join works.Hope this helps!
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp